# Adding 1 to 0001 vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a char array with a length of 4. I am attempting to create a way to add 1 to this char array and produce a string "0002".

I can convert the char array to an integer in order to add 1 to it, but the issue is I am losing the leading zeros in the process. Is there a way to preserve the zeros in the addition?

Some examples of output I want..
if endCode is "0009" and I add 1, I want "0010"
if endCode is "0999" and I add 1, I want "1000"

I am losing the zeros with my current code..

```
(Convert.ToInt32(New String(endCode)) + j).ToString
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're so close. Only 5 characters short. You just need a format string:

```
(Convert.ToInt32(New String(endCode)) + j).ToString("D4")
```

Though one wonders why or how this data came to be a character array in the first place.

Comment: The almighty ToString! I tend to forget about things it can do. Here is [a reference to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). +1

Comment: I start with something like A0001AB or 0001C or other variations of alpha numeric, I have to compare that one is greater than the other via the numeric piece. So I converted the string to char array and cut out any alpha characters while preserving the position they were in in the starting string. Is there a better way? There probably is

Comment: Maybe: I'm thinking regex. It's a question worth asking.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to get zeroes back:

```
Dim s As String = "0001"
Dim i As Integer = 1
Console.WriteLine(CStr(CInt(s) + i).PadLeft(4, "0"c)) 'outputs 0002
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the edge case?  I don't think D4 will work for that.

```
    Dim encode As String = "9999"
    Dim encint As Integer = Integer.Parse(encode) + 1
    encode = encint.ToString("00000").Substring(1, 4)
```

Comment: From MSDN, D format specifier sets a minimum number of characters to be displayed. If less than that, it's padded with zeroes. This works: `encode = encint.ToString("D4") 'outputs 10000` Reference: [The Decimal ("D") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#DFormatString).

Comment: I took the OP to mean that the length had to be 4.  Hard to guess as usual.  Maybe the OP will clarify.